# PHP sum in while loop calculation

Tags: php, php-8.1

As an assignment I have to come up with a script in which the numbers are added together and I have to display this calculation by using a while. It's very old study material that I need to understand but I can't find anything on the internet that can help me in this problem.

**Example:**

- If the user enters 6, the calculation is: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21
- If the user enters 4, the calculation is: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>14 - Oefening 1</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            // Getal ophalen
            $getal_invoer = $_GET["getal"];

            $i = 1;
            $sum = 0;
            $number = $getal_invoer;

            while ($i <= $number) {
                $sum += $i;
                $i++;
            }

            echo "$sum";
        
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the sum works but I wonder how I can display the calculation now.

Comment: Add `echo (($i == 1) ? '' : '+') . $i;` inside your `while` loop and add a `echo '=';` after?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question @RobEyre but thanks for your answer. I was looking way too far...